# Is there a "Clear Board" option for Trello?

Tags: trello

Is there a way to delete all cards from a board in Trello?

Comment: You could copy a board, and choose not to copy the cards...

Answer (score 1):

The handiest way to **archive** all cards quickly is to use shortcuts.

- You can select the first one that you want to archive and the press on C as fast as possible.
- If you really need to **delete** rather than archive you will have to select *Archived Items* from the Show Menu | More options and delete the cards one by one
- With your board open press ? to find more useful shortcuts